# Is the Play framework a container? I am unclear how it runs code

Tags: playframework-2.0, playframework-2.2

So when you create a new play project using the play tool:

> ~/play-2.2.1/play new MyProject

it creates a skeleton project in a new directory called MyProject.

To run this project:

> ~/play-2.2.1/play run (from within the MyProject dir).

What actually happens here? Is the play tool then importing the code from MyProject into a container (like Tomcat) and running it? I was under the assumption that it uses Netty and not the J2EE servlets etc. So why do we need to invoke the 'play' program to run the code in MyProject directory? Didn't the 'new project' script copy everything it needs?

I am kinda confused as to the model at work here. It appears that the project code is not complete without the play/ code to?

Grateful for any advice and pointers here.

Comment: You can't run the project from play-2.2.1 folder, but from your `MyProject` dir. You create the project in play folder (or through a global `play` env variable), but run it into your specific project folder with `play run`. (assuming you have well configured your `play` env variable)

Comment: I'm sorry, that I know. I am asking specifically **why** we need to invoke another program (play) to run our code. Is that not just a container?

Comment: Surely to provide the compilation SBT tasks and running tasks (generating compiled Scala templates, managing default SBT tasks for a Play project, etc...) All tasks for managing the project before running IMHO

Comment: @Mik378 - so I am getting the feeling that mastering Play (either the Java version or the Scala version) it is first a pre-requisite to know  SBT? I guess that 'common' files/libs like netty are not shipped with play but instead are pulled down when the app is first run? Am I on to something here? Thanks

Comment: Yes, at first launch, Play downloads all the artefacts it needs, additionally to those already provided from Play `local` folder (`io.netty` is already provided there out of the box). I would say that mastering some SBT basis is a pre-requisite to play with Play.

Answer (score 2):

No, there’s no container. Instead, your application is a stand-alone Java application that includes Play as a library dependency, so there’s no one-thing-inside-another-thing.

During development, sbt launches your application, which you can see as the last line of the `play` command, which is just a shell script.

When you package your application for production using `play dist`, you get a standalone application in a ZIP file, e.g. `target/universal/myapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.zip`. This contains a shell script that runs the application in the same way: see `unzip -p target/universal/myapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.zip play-slick-examples-1.0-SNAPSHOT/bin/myapp`.

Comment: thanks, that was very informative. So the 'play' command is really just a wrapper around the sbt ?

Comment: Kinda. It's an SBT plugin that adds some extra functionality. You can use sbt directly as long as you include the plugin dependency in project/plugins.sbt.

play shell command just calls sbt with the proper goals.

Comment: If there's no container, my application is responsible for implementing the servlet functionalities? e.g. who listens on a port and read/write to a network socket when someone send in a request?